# JS localStorage удаление элементов списка из массива local storage

Tags: javascript, json, localstorage

Как сделать так чтобы при клике на крестик(класс close) удалялся элемент из списка(то бишь из массива array). Я использую JSON localStorage это для меня в новинку. В newFun() я использую div.style.display = "none"; но после обновления страницы, все что было в массиве снова появляется. Начало с функции first().

```js
function newFun() {
  for (var i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
    close[i].onclick = function() {
      var div = this.parentElement;
      div.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

function work(include) {
  var newLi = document.createElement('li');
  newLi.innerHTML = include;
  list.appendChild(newLi);
  var allLi = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
  for (var i = 0; i < allLi.length; i++) {
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
    span.className = "close";
    span.appendChild(txt);
    allLi[i].appendChild(span);
  }
  newFun();
}

function first() {
  var array = [];

  if (!localStorage.commentData) {
    localStorage.commentData = [];
  } else {
    array = JSON.parse(localStorage.commentData);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    work(array[i]);
    newFun(array[i]);
  }

  var button = document.getElementById('button');
  button.onclick = function() {
    var input = document.getElementById('input');
    var value = input.value;
    input.value = "";

    array.push(value);
    localStorage.commentData = JSON.stringify(array);
    work(value);
  }
}
first();
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <header>
    <h1>ToDoList</h1>
  </header>

  <div id="main">
    <input id="input" maxlength="40" type="text" placeholder="New task">
    <button id="button">ADD</button>
  </div>

  <div id="list">
    <ul>
      <!--<li></li>-->
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: функция `newFunc` только лишь скрывает блок. Она не удаляет элемент из хранилища. Нужно  добавить соответствующий код

Comment: newFun() походу вообще не работает. Ей передаются аргументы в коде но она сама не содержит аргументов. close внутри тоже непонятно где объявлен.